# Problems with log-log histograms

Tags: histograms

I'm using a custom function to create Log-Log Histograms of my data. It uses the CustomTicks` package (in LevelScheme, http://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/) to display Log Ticks.

```
Needs["CustomTicks`"];

domainSizesHistogram[data_List,opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=
    Module[{},(
    Histogram[
        Log[10,data],
        {-0.05,5.05,0.1},
        "LogCount",
        opts,
        AxesLabel->{"Basin of attraction", "Number of attractors"},
        PlotRange->{Automatic,{-1,9}},
        Ticks->{CustomTicks`LogTicks[0,5],Automatic}
    ]
)]
```

It's got to be Log-Log because my simulations produce highly varied output and I would like to generate histograms to quickly compare the output of different runs.

Although the function generally works fine, it sometimes produces incorrect histograms.

```
data1 = {32, 20, 63, 234, 12, 50, 1, 332, 11, 210, 116, 88, 11, 68, 194, 202, \
11, 46, 116, 3, 41, 236, 41, 9, 23, 
48, 3, 52, 72, 20, 10, 9, 191, 52, 148, 50, 15, 105, 92, 130, 50, \
12, 244, 131, 159, 55, 189, 161, 83, 
17, 22, 7, 36, 51, 15, 132, 130, 42, 6, 51, 79, 39, 10, 4, 32, 13, \
63, 83, 68, 28, 8, 1, 48, 44, 144, 28, 
4, 19, 19, 54, 71, 276, 32, 39, 1, 20, 38, 72, 64, 60, 3, 93, 28, \
17, 56, 50, 7, 41, 3, 39, 11, 4, 30, 
49, 58, 7, 87, 15, 10, 13, 4, 51, 8, 6, 42, 21, 67, 8, 14, 19, 4, \
2, 49, 56, 15, 3, 58, 11, 5, 15, 5, 4, 
1, 27, 9, 34, 41, 3, 13, 14, 48, 69, 5, 38, 26, 8, 31, 23, 2, 21, \
28, 22, 28, 40, 14, 1, 14, 19, 1, 1, 
19, 8, 3, 35, 3, 61, 1, 18, 23, 21, 25, 28, 42, 5, 2, 11, 9, 3, 2, \
1, 50, 56, 13, 9, 14, 5, 19, 2, 2, 12, 
67, 6, 11, 1, 14, 7, 73, 23, 11, 2, 4, 10, 10, 3, 2, 8, 12, 4, 12, \
1, 8, 43, 6, 10, 15, 7, 6, 9, 9, 17, 
4, 6, 9, 2, 7, 9, 4, 2, 3, 25, 7, 2, 18, 4, 5, 13, 1, 16, 5, 13, \
25, 9, 13, 13, 2, 5, 3, 2, 2, 3, 10, 8, 
32, 12, 4, 5, 14, 6, 2, 6, 26, 4, 15, 10, 3, 11, 10, 8, 5, 6, 3, \
6, 2, 12, 3, 2, 7, 19, 14, 21, 6, 13, 2, 
21, 3, 5, 1, 3, 6, 4, 2, 15, 2, 11, 6, 12, 2, 2, 10, 1, 14, 2, 5, \
1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 5, 2, 4, 7, 
7, 6, 4, 2, 2, 13, 12, 4, 10, 5, 2, 2, 3, 7, 4, 1, 8, 4, 2, 4, 3, \
8, 4, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 1, 5, 1, 6, 8, 6, 
3, 4, 6, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 8, 4, 1, 3, 1, 1, \
5, 2, 1, 6, 4, 2, 4, 6, 1, 5, 3, 4, 1, 
6, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 5, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, \
1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 
1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, \
5, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, \
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, \
2, 1, 1, 1, 1};

data2 = {2655, 72, 3862, 2414, 577, 307, 21, 38, 8, 41, 4, 1};
```

`domainSizesHistogram[data1]` produces a normal histogram: [image: Histogram of data1]

But `domainSizesHistogram[data2]` gives a histogram where the axes are all messed up: [image]

How can I fix the function to always produce a histogram with the same axes? I already tried to set a hard `PlotRange` for both axes, but this didn't produce the right results either. Some of my fixes seemed to produce the right axes, but then the bars would float above the horizontal axis.

Any help would be appriciated.

**Edit:**

After adding `AxesOrigin->{-0.05,-1}` to the function, a lot of problem were solved. However, now I get floating bars in some cases.

data3 = {4535, 5465};

And `domainSizesHistogram[data3]` produces this: [image: Histogram of data3]

Comment: Can't you use an option `AxesOrigin->{0,0}` ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks, `AxesOrigin -> {0,-1}` already gives some improvement, but I can't find the x-value so that values of 1 (10^0) on the horizontal axis fall within the graph.

Comment: You can get the position of the axes origin with `Cases[Histogram[data2, "Log", "LogCount"], 
 Rule[AxesOrigin, origin_] -> origin, Infinity ]`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks, thanks, that fixed most of the problems, however one nagging issue still remains. I edited my question with the last problem (as far as I can see right now).

Comment: Let's wait for some `LevelScheme` experts; I never used it and can't help further for now.

Comment: Possibly related?: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14572/121